# If every five point subset of a metric space can be isometrically embedded in the plane then is it possible for the metric space also?

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, isometry

Let $X$ be a metric space with at least $5$ points such that any five point subset of $X$ can be isometrically embedded in $\mathbb R^2$ , then is it true that $X$ can also be isometrically embedded in $\mathbb R^2$ ?

Comment: I know nothing about this, could you explain a little why you might expect this to be true?

Comment: @David C. Ulrich : You had written a long and involved answer , I thought of reading it today , but I see you have deleted it , was there some serious error in it ?

Comment: @Jose27 : Well , the five in the question I just arbitrarily chose , I know that the answer to the question is in negative if we wanted the real line instead of the plane ; but in plane I could get no where with it , so I asked

Comment: The answer was simply wrong, as @achillehui pointed out. Yesterday I didn't see how to salvage it, this morning I believe I see how to fix it. Having screwed up once I'm going to check things carefully before posting the fixed version - stay tuned. (I "proved" something about embedding in $\Bbb R^n$, by induction. My version of the case $n=1$ was wrong, but having been given the correct version for $n=1$ I believe the induction is ok, although there's one new lemma needed.)

Comment: Btw yes, $5$ is the right number for $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Answer undeleted.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

"Embeddings" below are isometric; $(X,d)$ is a metric space.

In fact $X$ can be embedded in $\Bbb R^n$ if and only if every subset of $X$ containing no more than $n+3$ points can be embedded in $\Bbb R^n$. Thanks to @achillehui for noticing that the first version of this post was wrong, for stating the correct version of the result, and for telling us it's due to Menger (*Untersuchungen über allgemeine Metrik*, Mathematische Annalen, 100:75–163, 192) way back in 1928. **Edit** I've finally seen how to give an example showing that $n+3$ is best possible. See the **bonus** section at the bottom.

The proof is by induction on $n$. You may notice that the structure of the proof for $n=1$ is identical to the structure of the induction step. In fact the case $n=1$ could be derived by induction from the case $n=0$. That might involve some head-scratching; it seems best just to give the case $n=1$ separately.

In the case $n=1$ various plausible but not quite trivial lemmas can be replaced by the following triviality: If $X$ can be embedded in $\Bbb R$, $a,b$ are two distinct points of $X$, $x,y$ are two distinct points of $\Bbb R$, and $|x-y|=d(a,b)$, then there is exactly one embedding $f:X\to\Bbb R$ with $f(a)=x$ and $f(b)=y$. (For existence, replace the given embedding $g$ by $\pm g+c$. For uniqueness, note that if $|f(a)-t|=|f(a)-s|$ and $t\ne s$ then $f(a)=(s+t)/2$, and  similarly for $f(b)$.)

**Theorem 1.** $X$ can be embedded in $\Bbb R$ if and only if any four points of $X$ can be embedded in $\Bbb R$.

Proof: For the less trivial direction: We may assume $X$ has more than one point. Choose $p,q\in X$ and define $f(p)=0$, $f(q)=d(p,q)$. 
Suppose $r\in X$, $r\ne p,q$. The hypothesis and the comment above (with $\{p,q,r\}$ in place of $X$) shows that there is a unique embedding $g$ of $p,q,r$ with $g(p)=f(p)$ and $g(q)=f(q)$. Define $f(r)=g(r)$.

We have defined $f:X\to\Bbb R$ such that $|f(r)-f(p)|=d(r,p)$ and $|f(r)-f(q)|=d(r,q)$ for every $r$. We are done if we can show that $|f(r)-f(s)|=d(r,s)$ for $r,s\notin\{p,q\}$. As above there is a unique embedding $g$ of $p,q,r,s$ in $\Bbb R$ with $g(p)=f(p)$ and $g(q)=f(q)$. Uniqeness of the embedding of $p,q,r$ shows that $g(r)=f(r)$. Similarly $g(s)=f(s)$, so $|f(r)-f(s)|=|g(r)-g(s)|=d(r,s)$. QED.

The case $n>1$ requires a few preliminaries.

**Lemma 0.** Suppose $x_1,\dots,x_N,y_1,\dots,y_N\in\Bbb R^n$ and $|x_j-x_k|=|y_j-y_k|$ for all $j,k$. Then there is an isometry $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$ with $f(x_j)=y_j$.

Proof: Let $v_j=x_j-x_0$, $w_j=y_j-y_0$. We have $|v_j|=|w_j|$ and $|v_j-v_k|=|w_j-w_k|$. The parallelogram law shows that $|v_j+v_k|=|w_j+w_k|$, so that $v_j\cdot v_k=w_j\cdot w_k$ by polarization. Hence $$\left|\sum t_jv_j\right|=\left|\sum t_jw_j\right|.$$In particular $\sum t_jv_j=0$ if and only if $\sum t_jw_j=0$, so that there exists a linear map $T:span(v_j)\to span(w_j)$ with $$T\left(\sum t_jv_j\right)=\sum t_jw_j.$$Now $T$ is evidently an isometry; extend $T$ to an orthogonal map from $\Bbb R^n$ to itself by mapping the orthogonal complement of $span(v_j)$ to the orthogonal complement of $span(w_j)$. QED.

**Definition** We say $F\subset\Bbb R^n$ is *coplanar* if there exist $c\in\Bbb R$ and $v\in\Bbb R^n$ with $v\ne0$ such that $x\cdot v=c$ for every $x\in F$.

**Lemma 1.** Suppose $x_1,\dots,x_N\in\Bbb R^{n}$ and $\{x_1,\dots,x_N\}$ are not coplanar. If $|x_j-y|=|x_j-z|$ for all $j$ then $y=z$.

Proof: Saying $|x_j-y|=|x_j-z|$ is the same as $(x_j-\frac{y+z}{2})\cdot(z-y)=0$; if $y\ne z$ this says that $x_1,\dots,x_N$ are coplanar. QED.

**Lemma 2.** Suppose $F\subset\Bbb R^n$ is not coplanar. Then $F$ has a non-coplanar subset containing exactly $n+1$ points.

Proof: Fix $x_0\in F$. The set $\{x-x_0:x\in F\}$ spans $\Bbb R^n$, so it must contain a basis. QED.

**Theorem 2.** $X$ can be embedded in $\Bbb R^n$ if and only if every subset of $X$ containing no more than $n+3$ points can be embedded in $\Bbb R^n$.

Proof: The proof is by induction on $n$. The case $n=1$ is exactly Theorem 1 above. Suppose then that the theorem holds for embeddings into $\Bbb R^n$, and suppose that every subset of $X$ containing no more than $n+4$ points can be embedded in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$.

We want to show that $X$ can be embedded in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$, so we may assume that $X$ cannot be embedded in $\Bbb R^n$. By induction there exists $S \subset X$, with $|S|\le n+3$, such that $S$ cannot be embedded in $\Bbb R^n$. By hypothesis there exists an embedding $f:S\to\Bbb R^{n+1}$. Since $S$ cannot be embedded in $\Bbb R^n$, the image $f(S)$ cannot be coplanar. Applying Lemma 2 we see this: There exist $p_1,\dots,p_{n+2}\in X$ and an embedding $f$ of $p_1,\dots,p_{n+2}$ in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ such that if we set $x_j=f(p_j)$ then $x_1,\dots,x_{n+2}$ are not coplanar.

Suppose that $q\ne p_1,\dots,p_{n+2}$. The hypothesis and Lemma 1 show that there is exactly one $x\in\Bbb R^{n+1}$ with $|x-x_j|=d(q,p_j)$ for all $j$; define $f(q)=x$.

We have defined $f:X\to\Bbb R^{n+1}$. To show that $f$ is an isometry it is enough to show that if $r,q\ne p_1,\dots p_{n+2}$ then $|f(r)-f(q)|=d(r,q)$. The hypothesis shows that there is an embedding $g:\{r,q,p_1,\dots,p_{n+2}\}\to\Bbb R^{n+1}$, and now Lemma 0 shows that there exists such a $g$ with $g(p_j)=f(p_j)$. Now Lemma 1 shows that $g(r)=f(r)$ and $g(q)=f(q)$, so that $|f(r)-f(q)|=|g(r)-g(q)|=d(r,q)$. QED

---

**Bonus** In fact $n+3$ is best possible.

In the first version of this answer I "proved" Theorem 2 with $2n+1$ in place of $n+3$. The induction was ok, more or less the same as above; the problem was that I'd "proved", largely on the basis of wishful thinking, that Theorem 1 was true with $3$ in place of $4$. Thanks again to @achillehui for pointing out that was wrong.

I think the simplest way to show that $4$ is best possible for $n=1$ is this: Let $X$ consist of the four points $(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)$, *with* the $\ell^1$ metric (that is, $d(x,y)=|x_1-y_1|+|x_2-y_2|$). It's easy to see that any $3$-point subset of $X$ embeds in $\Bbb R$, and that $X$ itself does not.

That example actually generalizes to $n\ge1$, but when it's presented that way it's not so clear how. I'm going to give a fairly careful description of an example showing that $5$ is best possible for $n=2$. I claim that it *is* clear that the example below generalizes to show that $n+3$ is best possible for $n\ge2$, and I leave as an unimportant exercise to show how the example for $n=1$ above is actually the same construction as what I give for $n=2$, if you look at it right.

Let $a_1,a_2,a_3$ be the vertices of an equilateral triangle in the plane. Let $c$ be the center of that triangle. Let $X=\{a_1,a_2,a_3,c,c'\}$, where $c'$ is something else. Define a metric on $X$: First, define the distance between any two points of $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,c\}$ to be the euclidean distance as points in the plane. Define $$d(c',a_j)=d(c,a_j)$$and set $$d(c,c')=2h,$$where $h$ is the perpendicular distance from $c$ to one of the sides of our triangle. No need to scratch your head over the triangle inequality, that will follow when we show that any $4$-point subset of $X$ can be embedded in the plane.

If we remove $c'$ from $X$ what remains *is* a subset of the plane. If we remove $c$ we can set $f(c')=c$ to embed the remaining four points.

Suppose we remove $a_3$. Map each of the points $a_1,a_2,c$ to itself. Map $c'$ to the point on the other side of the segment $[a_1,a_2]$, so we get a rhombus with diagonals $[a_1,a_2]$ and $[c,f(c')]$.

So any four points of $X$ can be embedded in the plane. But $X$ itself does not embed in the plane; if this is not clear it can be proved from Lemma 1 and Lemma 0 using arguments as above.

So $5$ is best possible for $n=2$. And I assert again that the same construction shows that $n+3$ is best possible for $n\ge2$; if anyone wants to write a formal description go for it. (For $n=3$ we start with the vertices and center of a regular tetrahedron and add a sort of duplicate of the center point...)

Comment: @achillehui Finally saw how to show $n+3$ is best possible; thought you might be interested. Thanks again...

Comment: nice, it is good to see a proof that $n+3$ is best possible.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich : Sorry to bother you after such a long time but I cannot understand the preliminary remarks before Theorem 1 , about the existence-uniqueness of $f$ ; could you please elaborate how do you construct such an $f$ and why it is unique ?

Comment: @user228169 I can try to be a little more explicit, but I fear much of what I write is going to be just repeating what I wrote. If the following does not do it for you try to be more explicit about exactly what steps you don't follow. In that paragraph we are given an embedding $g:X\to\Bbb R$. We are given $a,b\in X$ and $x,y\in\Bbb R$ with $|x-y|=d((a,b)$. Now since $|x-y|=|g(a)-g(b)|$ it's possible to choose $\pm$ and $c$ so that if we set $f=\pm g+c$ then $f(a)=\pm g(a)+c=x$ and $f(b)=\pm g(b)+c=y$. (Consider two cases, depending on whether $y-x$ and $g(b)-g(a)$ have the same sign.) [...]

Comment: @user228169 That gives existence of an embedding $f$ with thhe stated property. For uniqueness: Suppose $f$ and $f'$ are embeddings with the stated property. Suppose $c\in X$. Then $|f(c)-x|=|f'(c)-x|$ and $|f(c)-y|=|f'(c)-y|$. if $f(c)\ne f'(c)$ this would imply that $x=(f(c)-f'(c))/2$ and $y=(f(c)-f'(c))/2$, so $x=y$, contradiction.