# Planar embedding of finite metric spaces

Tags: metric-spaces

Given a finite metric space $(X, d)$ and a positive integer $n$, what is the ‘best’ way to test whether $X$ embeds isometrically in $\mathbb R^{n - 1}$?  Note that this is more general than the question in the title, which is what first occurred to me.  (Although I haven't thought about it very much, this is probably automatically possible for $n$ at least the cardinality of $X$, and there are examples (like the indiscrete metric, or, I think, any ultrametric space) where the bound is sharp.)

The meaning of ‘best’ is intentionally ambiguous.  For $n = 2$, here’s a solution that may not be optimal:  find the maximal distance between two points, and check that it is achieved for a unique pair of points.  Call these $x_0$ and $x_1$.  There is a unique map $X \to \mathbb R$ sending each $x \in X$ to $d(x_0, x)$, and an isometric embedding exists if and only if this particular map is one.

EDIT:  A related question about [deducing planarity from 5-point embeddings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1829820/if-every-five-point-subset-of-a-metric-space-can-be-isometrically-embedded-in-th) is a beautiful result, but not quite what I want; it just reduces the question to:  how do I run this test if $n = \lvert X\rvert + 4$?