# Metric space of 5 points any 4 of which can be isometrically embedded in the plane but not all 5...

Tags: metric-spaces, isometry

Is there a five-point metric space, where any 4-point subset of it can be isometrically embedded in the Euclidean plane $\mathbb{R}^2$, but the whole metric space can't, and all 10 distances are positive integers?

This question was inspired by [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1829820) where no restriction was put on the distances. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1829853) describes an example where three of the distances are equal, and are $\sqrt3$ as large as the other seven.

I wondered if it was possible with all distances integer.

What I've tried: Various planar sets of four points, e.g. a 4 by 3 rectangle; a rhombus 5, 5, 5, 5 with diagonals 8, 6; a trapezium 4, 2, 3, 2 with diagonals 4, 4; a parallelogram 7, 4, 7, 4 with diagonals 9, 7; and various subsets of the equiangular hexagon 5, 3, 5, 3, 5, 3 with $AD=BE=CF=8$ and other diagonals 7. I can't get any of them to work. It seems that those attempts fail because the distances have too many different values. But a planar set of four points whose distances have a mere two different values is no good for this problem, because the distances need to have a ratio of $1:\sqrt3$ (as in the cited example), $1:\sqrt2$ (square) or $1:\phi$ (regular pentagon).